# IOS - Make http request with specific mime type

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, rest, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a REST service running on a local apache server. I am trying to send a http request to trigger it from an ios application. I have tried in numerous ways but the request doesn't seem to reach the server.

EDIT: The REST service decides what to call based on a specific MIME type, that's why I'm setting the content-type.

This is what I have at the moment for code:

```
- (IBAction)fetchTweet
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/Jersey/rest/hello"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request addValue:@"text/html; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request     delegate:self];

    self.connection = connection;
    [connection start];

}


- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    [self fetchTweet];
    self.label.text = @"Working";
}
```

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080216/request-with-nsurlrequest

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronous request. Try using the below code to this the server synchronously. At least this will make sure everything is running fine. responseData can be written in a file to see the response.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/Jersey/rest/hello"];

NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *responseData = nil;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request addValue:@"text/html; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&theError];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to use this but it says that there is "No Known class method for selector 'sendSychronousRequest:returningResponse.'

Comment: Can you check the Frameworks group -> Other Frameworks and check if foundation framework exists there or not.

Comment: Foundation framework is there. It's possible I may have setup something incorrectly in the header file.

Comment: Go to your Project -> General tab -> See linked frameworks and Libraries and check if Cocoa frameworks and all other are added.

Comment: Under linked frameworks and libraries there is coreGraphics UIKit and Foundation frameworks.

Comment: No there it doesn't seem to be on the list you can add from.

Comment: Click on '+', it will open a sheet then search search for 'cocoa' and just add it

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, it's not in that list.

Comment: Import this file into the .h file and try #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Comment: I did the #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> part. I think I need to install the command line tools to get the cocoa framework, so I'm doing that now.

Comment: yeah thats the only thing now i think you are missing,

Comment: I was having trouble trying to add the cocoa framework, after reading around it seems I don't need it for ios development. The request still isn't reaching the server though.