# NSURLRequest - Make calls to local server without internet connection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurlrequest

I have set up a local server on which I have a database. I want my app, written in Xcode objective-C 6.1.1, to make NSURLRequests to the database on the local server in order to GET and POST data.

The problem is that NSURLRequests realises that I don't have a legit internet connection and sends me back an Status Code which says I don't have internet connection. I don't WANT internet connection, as a matter of fact I CAN'T have an internet connection in this current project.

How can I prevent NSURLRequest to check for internet connection? In the safari browser on whatever device I try to run my app I can access the data, but not in the app through NSURLRequest.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: It returns -1009, and the error message states that there is no internet connection. As soon as I have an internet connection it works flawlessly.

Comment: Please post the error code

Comment: This is the exact message from the localization on the NSError object: Internet appears to be offline, Status Code: -1009

Comment: probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080216/request-with-nsurlrequest

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved. Simple problem: Wrong url outside was trying to be reached instead of the url for the server...