# How to send json post values to a remote server and get the results with iOS 5?

Tags: ios, json, http, post

I'm new to IOS 5 and I'm trying to send json values to a remote php server, which will send me back the results. This is my dispach call so far:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: http://www.someurl/example.php];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

I know this is mainly a GET request. How can I send post values? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to resort to NSURLRequest (or another request object) to do a POST.
Try this question, [Append data to a POST NSUrlRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest), as an example of how to send data and handle the result.