# How to submit web forms through objective-c code (send POST information and retain cookies)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, nsxmlparser

The website that I'm creating an app for doesn't have an API, but I need to use it. I can get information easily from the website by parsing the HTML and processing the nodes, but I need to be able to input data as well. For instants, I need to "log in" with information the user has already entered into the settings. To do this in real life, I would click the username field and then the password field and then hit ok, but through code, I need to send it directly through POST.

Also, I need to be able to retain the session cookies.

How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append data to a POST NSUrlRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest)

Comment: Well you said you need to use API, so how about creating a web service?