# How do I send an Image to a web services that takes Stream.IO from iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, rest

This is the web services function I wan't to call (JSON).

```
string UploadFileContent(Stream content,string uploadFileId)
```

[Stream description.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f86tw9e)

How do a send an `UIImage` (Base64 encoded, or `NSInputStream`) using `NSMutableRequest`? Iam using Objective-C (ARC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your image in base64 on a NSString, you can do :

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

After, you can send your request as a string. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest).

Comment: I talked to the WS-guys and they had some faulty code. I will accept this as the correct answer, even if I haven't got the chance to test it yet. Thanks.