# How to send a variable from iOS to php file

Tags: php, ios, nsurl

I have a simple task, send one variable to a php page via GET. Nothing I seem to find works, and all are seemingly more than I need.

It seems I need code to set NSURL string, NSURL request, then execute.

Can someone perhaps paste me some simple code to just execute a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/trendypieces/site/ios/processLatest.php?caption=yosa
```

Thanks!

Here's the most current iteration of something that doesn't work, seems closer though as it actually throws back the error alert. Dunno what that error is...but....

```
//construct an URL for your script, containing the encoded text for parameter value
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:
                   @"http://localhost/trendypieces/site/ios/processLatest.php?caption=yosa"]];

    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {

        alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Posted" message:@"Done"
                                                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    } else {
        alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Done"
                                                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    }
    [alertsuccess show];
```

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html and ask specific questions if you don't understand anything. Just asking for code is against the spirit of the site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append data to a POST NSUrlRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest)

Comment: ok then, adding code. i've tried SOOO many iterations of this code in the past 10 hours I'm not sure if its even useful. It just seemed like a very basic question for someone with experience. Sorry to have offend you.

Comment: Nobody is offended, just normal practice at SO to flag similar questions :)

Comment: @DominikHadl That post is a very different topic: That's because someone was trying to do a `POST` request with parameters in the URL (which is wrong, it should be in the body). But this question is about adding parameters to a `GET` request, and if he really wanted to do `GET` it _has to_ be in the URL, not the body, precisely the opposite scenario as suggested by that other question. I suspect the problem here may be the fact that he's starting connection two times, or something else. But not because he didn't put the parameters in the body.

Comment: @harp Did you implement `connection:didFailWithError:`? What `NSError` did that report? Also, I assume you're running this on the simulator (as `localhost` would not work from the device).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points:

1. When you create a `NSURLConnection` with `initWithRequest:delegate:`, it automatically starts the connection. Do *not* call the `start` method yourself (in some cases, it can interfere with the initial connection). That is only intended for when you use `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` with `NO` for that final parameter.
2. You then say:

   > Current code that yields no active result (from within an IBAction function)

   Your code would not yield any "active result" within the `IBAction` method. It would call the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods. Have you implemented them? Notably, make sure you also implement `connection:didFailWithError:`, which will tell you if there were any connection errors.

   If you need the result in the `IBAction` method, you should use the `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest`.
3. Going to the title of this question, "how to send a variable", you should be careful about just adding user input to a URL. (This isn't your immediate problem why you're not getting any reply, but this is important when sending the contents of a variable to a web server.)

   Notably, the `caption=xxx` portion, the `xxx` cannot contain spaces or reserved characters like `+`, `&`, etc. What you have to do is percent-encode it. So, you should:

   ```
   NSString *caption = ... // right now this is @"yosa", but presumably this will eventually be some variable

   NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
   self.receivedData = data;
   // [data release];  // if not ARC, insert this line

   //initialize url that is going to be fetched.
   NSString *encodedCaption = [self percentEscapeString:caption];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/trendypieces/site/ios/processLatest.php?caption=%@", encodedCaption]];

   //initialize a request from url
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   //initialize a connection from request
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   self.connection = connection;
   // [connection release]; // if not ARC, insert this line

   // DO NOT start the connection AGAIN
   //[connection start];
   ```

   Where that `percentEscapeString` is defined as:

   ```
   - (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
   {
       NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
       return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
   }
   ```

   (Note, there is a promising `NSString` method, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, that does something very similar, but resist the temptation to use that. It handles some characters (e.g. the space character), but not some of the others (e.g. the `+` or `&` characters).)
4. Finally, you say that this is a `GET` request (which, implies you're not changing anything on the server). If it really is a `GET` request, see my prior point. But if this request is really updating data, you should be doing a `POST` request (where the `caption=yosa` goes in the body of the request, not the URL). This has another advantage as there are limitations as to how long a URL can be (and therefore what how long the parameters can be when you submit them in the URL in a `GET` request).

   Anyway, if you wanted to create a `POST` request, it would be like:

   ```
   NSString *caption = ... // right now this is @"yosa", but presumably this will eventually be some variable

   NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
   self.receivedData = data;
   // [data release];  // if not ARC, insert this line

   //create body of the request
   NSString *encodedCaption = [self percentEscapeString:caption];
   NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"caption=%@", encodedCaption];
   NSData *postBody = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   //initialize url that is going to be fetched.
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/trendypieces/site/ios/processLatest.php"];

   //initialize a request from url
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   //initialize a connection from request
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   self.connection = connection;
   // [connection release]; // if not ARC, insert this line
   ```
5. While your initial code sample was using a delegate-based `NSURLConnection`, you've revised your answer to use `dataWithContentsOfURL`. If you really don't want to use the delegate-based `NSURLConnection`, then use its `sendAsynchronousRequest` instead, which offers the simplicity of `dataWithContentsOfURL`, but allows you to use either `GET` or `POST` requests, as well as performing it asynchronously. So, create the `NSMutableURLRequest` as shown above (use the appropriate method code depending upon whether you're `GET` or `POST`), eliminate the lines that instantiate the `NSMutableData` and the `NSURLConnection` and replace that with:

   ```
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

       if (!data) {
           NSLog(@"Error = %@", connectionError);

           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alert show];

           return;
       }

       NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

       NSLog(@"Data = %@", serverOutput);

       UIAlertView *alert;

       if ([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
           alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Posted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       } else {
           alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Not OK" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       }

       [alert show];
   }];
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried all of these,many errors.Don't care if POST or GET,just want to send one variable to page. Insertion php
 page works whether I hit it POST or GET, takes anything. When I try the last code there,POST method, I get these errors:
self.receivedData = data;...'prop not found on AppViewController'
[data release];...'ARC forbids explicit message send of release'
NSString *encodedCaption = [self percentEscapeString:caption]; .. gets 'no visible @interface for 'APPViewController' declares the selector
self.connection = connection;...'prop not found'
[connection release];...several

Comment: @harp I don't understand the errors you provide, because your code sample would have generated the same errors. E.g., your code sample had `release` statements in it, so I assumed you weren't using ARC. If you're using ARC, remove those `release` statements. Your code sample referenced the `receivedData` and `connection` class properties, so I assumed you had such properties (`NSMutableData` and `NSURLConnection` properties, respectively). Add them if you don't have them. Re the `percentEscapeString` method warning, did you add that method (provided in my answer, above)?

Comment: Re `GET` or `POST`, I don't care which you use either. Obviously if you're updating the server, you should use `POST`. If you're just retrieving data, you should use `GET`. I'm just suggesting that you make sure that you pick one and use the appropriate method for setting the parameter (the body data for `POST`, the URL for `GET`). And change the PHP code accordingly (`$_POST` or `$_GET`, as appropriate). The only reason I belabored that point was that the other, well-intentioned, answer just got that backwards.

Comment: haha yeah i saw that that! those errors are just what immediately popped up when i pasted your code. I did add the trailing method which resolved a few errors not all. So I should have added a library or include for NSMutableData and NSURLConnection ?

Comment: and btw i tried another chunk of code that may be getting closer, I edited the original post at the top to show it. It at least recognizes some sort of failure. lol.

Comment: @harp I notice that you've now changed this to use dataWithContentsOfURL. Two points there. First, you can't do `POST` requests that way (which is ok if you've concluded `GET` is sufficient). Second, it's inadvisable to use synchronous network calls (your app will freeze during the network operation). Use `[NSURLRequest sendAsynchronousRequest:...]` (see point 6 above) if you don't want to avoid complications of the rich, delegate-based `NSURLConnection` API.

Comment: arg...i appreciate your comments but this isn't helping. There is no point 6 above. I can't tell what in that last code specifies get or post. i never would have thought such a simple task would so hard. i've been programming for years and years, this shouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: @harp Point 5, above.

Comment: ok so i replaced with your code from number 4, added the escapeString function, now i have just two red errors:
self.receivedData = data; === Property 'receivedData not found on object 'APPViewController'
self.connection = connection; === Property 'connection not found on object 'APPViewController'

Comment: @harp Let's step back for a sec: If you use option 4, that means that you have implemented the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods. Have you? Then you must have property for the `NSMutableData` already defined, no? What did you call it, if not `receivedData`? I'm confused by your question about these two lines from my code sample, because these two lines are from _your original code sample._ lol. If you haven't implemented the delegate-based `NSURLConnection` code, then it might be easier to pursue option 5.

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem was trying to hit localhost from the phone and not the simulator, duh. The code that runs successfully now is below. Thanks to all for the help.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/trendypieces/site/ios/processLatest.php?caption=mycaption"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    returnData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is adapted for POST with two variables, thanks to @Rob for code from another post.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.5/trendypieces/site/ios/processLatest.php"];

    NSString *var2 = @"variable2";
    NSString *postString    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"caption=%@&var2=%@", _captionField.text, var2];
    NSData   *postBody      = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //initialize a request from url
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //initialize a connection from request, any way you want to, e.g.
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```