# Using Native iOS View to Submit Google Form Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, form-submit

I am wondering if there is a way to create a form in a native iOS app and submit it via Google Forms. Here is an example on a web page of what I'm wanting to do natively in an iOS app.

http://onmyhonorband.com/streetteam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see how to create a URL Request with post variables over at this post:

[Append data to a POST NSURLRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest)

You can find the URL and variable names by inspecting your current form's HTML.  In your case post to the URL:

`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1vlYPlNi4xJv6JCHpLrHD6oSrYgUqWOrzF8z6KJjTVuE/formResponse`

Paramaters will be `entry.1615511943`, `entry.1186557728`, etc. You'll also find these in the HTML input's 'name'.

Set the doc type like this:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

The data itself is just strings, you'll have to build a UI and pull them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, I used this method in this repo: https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

Here is the tutorial of how to set it up:
https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs/blob/master/Log%20To%20GoogleDocs.md

Heres the code to do it:

```
private static var googleFormLink: String!
private static var googleFormAppVersionField: String!
private static var googleFormUserInfoField: String!
private static var googleFormMethodInfoField: String!
private static var googleFormErrorTextField: String!

/// Setup Google Form links
static func setupOnlineLogs(#formLink: String, versionField: String, userInfoField: String, methodInfoField: String, textField: String) {
    googleFormLink = formLink
    googleFormAppVersionField = versionField
    googleFormUserInfoField = userInfoField
    googleFormMethodInfoField = methodInfoField
    googleFormErrorTextField = textField
}

private static func sendError(#text: String) {
    var url = NSURL(string: googleFormLink)
    var postData = googleFormAppVersionField + "=" + text
    postData += "&" + googleFormUserInfoField + "=" + "anothertext"                
    postData += "&" + googleFormMethodInfoField + "=" + "anothertext" 
    postData += "&" + googleFormErrorTextField + "=" + "anothertext" 

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started working with Joe's response above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23451577/879231) but was getting a 404 on the request without adding an `/e` after the `/d` that was in the his URL. Found this by comparing the share form link with what Joe had. Little testing and got it working. Below is my code using Swift and AlamoFire just cause I already had it in my project. *Note: The `contactInfo.paramaters` I'm passing in is a just a simple struct with a computed `parameters` property to spit out the collected info from my iOS version of the form.*

```
func upload() {
  var headers = HTTPHeaders()
  headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  Alamofire.request("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<enter your forms ID here>/formResponse",
            method: .post,
            parameters: contactInfo.paramaters,
            headers: headers).validate().response { (response) in
              print(response)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follow:

1. create some uitextfields as some input text field
2. then submit those form values using AFNetworking

Comment: No need for AFNetworking, NSURLConnection is sufficient.