# How to send a multi line string to URL - Objective C

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I have a Text View which will be used to input data on multiple lines. The string will then be posted to an URL to a php file and then to a MYSQL Database.

The problem i am having is that the string will not be send if i use multiple lines. I used the following to get around the fact that (Spaces) could not be sent via a URL:

```
hostStr = [hostStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Is there anything similar to this I can do to get the string to return with multiple lines?

Comment: are you "sending" it as a url parameter?

Comment: Yes, for example as domain.com/addNote?Note=This Is A New Note\nContinue Down here.

Something like this

Comment: Why not a proper POST request?

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios

Comment: @Yuyutsu That shows how to post, but is a poor answer because it doesn't contemplate percent escaping (which should be done anyway, but is critical for this particular question). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22725563/1271826 for some percent escaping code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[hostStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` ?

Comment: This is not adequate. It takes care of spaces and newline characters, but it won't percent escape other characters that need encoding (notably `+` or `&` would be problematic if they ever appeared in the string).

Comment: Good point. I think `[hostStr stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]]` would be better

Comment: Yep. Technically, [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) qualifies this and instructs us that the only characters that should never be percent escaped are the unreserved characters, include `alphanumericCharacterSet` plus "-", ".", "_", and "~". So I would advise adding those four character to the allowed characters set (though, in practice, it really doesn't matter).