# Empty data while trying to send Post method request

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I'm trying to send me POST method Request, however when the post is sent the data that is stored in the database is empty i don't get the Value that i have sent this is what i tried:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/json/insertData.php?username=test&password=test"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: queryString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

All is good, only when the data is sent and i check the database i get en empty values, where is the mistake please.

And this is the code of my PHP file:

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $db   = "Users";


    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);

    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Can't connect to mysql server!");
    }

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($con,$db);

    if(!$db_select)
    {
        die("Can't get the selected db!");
    }

    $id       = "11";
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email    = "any1@any1.com";
    $gsm      = "91111111";

    $query = "INSERT INTO Logins VALUES($id,'$username','$password','$email',$gsm)";
    $query_exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if(!$query_exec)
    {
        die("Can't insert data");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code of your insertData.php.

Comment: ok, the question has been edited and the code has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer for this question, also you told me that i change the $_POST request to $_GET however as i said i want it post not GET. Finally i got the mistake i have to Encode the DATA using this code:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

After i added this code, the data has been added successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the variables `username` and `password` via GET. In your PHP script you have to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

Comment: i dont want to use get, i want to pass a post form how i can do it?

Comment: There is an example in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6149088/3647441

Answer (score 0):

in your Error url shows

> `http://localhost/json/insertData.php?username=test&password=test`

you can clearly see `username=test&password=test` have all data. It means your form `method="get"`,

So in your code

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: i dont want to use get, i want to pass a post form how i can do it?

Comment: check your submit action

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, in the form from the previous page, you should change the submitting form tag to include method="post".

```
<form method="post">
```