# how to submit a password with special characters from app to a web-server by NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

I have to login with my to a web-server.All works fine, but not generated passwords like |%<">{}¥^~ . How I have to encode passwords like this?

I create a User with password=|%<">{}¥^~
doset work
( for example a password like "user1234" works fine)

```
NSString *userName = self.usernameOutlet.text;
NSString *userPassword = self.passwordOutlet.text;
NSString *escapedString = [self.passwordOutlet.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
userPassword = escapedString;
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&password=%@",userName,userPassword];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXXXXXX/login"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

with passwords like "user1234" I get a cookie

with passwords like "|%<">{}¥^~" I get no cookie

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: but I did it. see code

NSString *escapedString = [self.passwordOutlet.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
userPassword = escapedString;

Comment: looks like the wrong character set. It should be URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet

Comment: No, `NSURLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` won’t quite work either. It will let `&` and `+` pass unescaped (because those are technically allowed in the “query” portion of a URL, but not in a value (or key) of a `x-www-form-urlencoded` payload).

Comment: the escapedString is "%7C%25%3C%22%3E%7B%7D%C2%A5%5E~" with **URLHostAllowedCharacterSet** and same with **URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet**

Comment: @Hape42 Try password of `"foo+bar&baz"`. It won’t escape the `+` or the `&`.

Comment: As an aside, `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated. We’d generally use `NSURLSession` nowadays...

Answer (score 1):

It’s tempting to want to use `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`, but that won’t work for all strings. Notably `&` and `+` will pass unescaped.

If you’re wondering why we must percent escape `&` and `+`, too, it’s because these two characters have a special meaning in `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. The `&` is used to delimit key-value pairs in a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, so it will truncate your password. And most web services translate a `+` to a space, so you’ll want to percent escape that, too.

So, let’s first define a character set that will work:

```
// NSCharacterSet+URLQueryValueAllowed.h

@interface NSCharacterSet (URLQueryValueAllowed)

@property (class, readonly, copy) NSCharacterSet *URLQueryValueAllowedCharacterSet;

@end
```

and

```
// NSCharacterSet+URLQueryValueAllowed.m

@implementation NSCharacterSet (URLQueryValueAllowed)

+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLQueryValueAllowedCharacterSet {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSCharacterSet *queryValueAllowed;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSMutableCharacterSet *allowed = [[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
        NSString *generalDelimitersToEncode = @":#[]@";   // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        NSString *subDelimitersToEncode = @"!$&'()*+,;=";

        [allowed removeCharactersInString:generalDelimitersToEncode];
        [allowed removeCharactersInString:subDelimitersToEncode];

        queryValueAllowed = [allowed copy];
    });
    return queryValueAllowed;
}

@end
```

Then, to make life easier for us, let’s define `NSDictionary` category for percent encoding a dictionary:

```
// NSDictionary+PercentEncoded.h

@interface NSDictionary (PercentEncoded)
- (NSString *)percentEncodedString;
- (NSData *)percentEncodedData;
@end
```

and

```
// NSDictionary+PercentEncoded.m

@implementation NSDictionary (PercentEncoded)
- (NSString *)percentEncodedString {
    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSCharacterSet *allowed = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryValueAllowedCharacterSet];

    for (NSString *key in self.allKeys) {
        NSString *encodedKey = [key stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:allowed];
        NSString *value = [[self objectForKey:key] description];
        NSString *encodedValue = [value stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:allowed];
        [results addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", encodedKey, encodedValue]];
    }
    return [results componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
}

- (NSData *)percentEncodedData {
    return [[self percentEncodedString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
@end
```

Then, your application code can do:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"login": userName, @"password": userPassword};
NSData *body = [dictionary percentEncodedData];
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. but it still doesn't work. I used the Password: **|%<>{}¥^~**

the server I try to login is no secret.

http://dailygammon.com/

Comment: What is the URL for your endpoint that you’re connecting to? I don’t see docs for their API endpoints. Without seeing more, it’s hard to comment. The character that concerns me is the `¥`, which is not an ASCII character and translates to two byte sequence. I also wonder about whether this endpoint that you’re connecting to is doing the right escaping/encoding of the strings you pass. E.g. `%` sometimes has a special meaning in some SQL interfaces. I’d suggest you try `%foo` and `¥foo` and ..., once for each characters, until you figure out which is the problem.

Comment: thank you for the hint to figure out wich character the problem is

All characters **|%<>{}"^~** work fine, only **¥** doesn't work